# memory and pass values in a Pointer in shared memory

Tags: c, struct, malloc, wait, shared-memory

I'm trying to pass some values between a parent and 10 child processes with shared memory and active wait.

Some values in the struct are pointers to allocate outside dynamic memory
The error is  showing when i'm trying to write a number in a string to pass a path file with numbers, but I can't since the memory is not there, I can only do it without a number.

```
typedef struct {
    char *path[10];
    char *word[10];
    int number_ocurrency[10];
    int flag[10];
} shared_data_type;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;
    int data_size = sizeof(shared_data_type),i;
    pid_t pid;
    shared_data_type *shared_data;

    if((fd = shm_open("/ex06_searchWord", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR))==-1)
    {
        perror("Error at shared memory allocation!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    ftruncate (fd, data_size);
    shared_data = (shared_data_type *)mmap(NULL,data_size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
    for(i=0; i<10;i++){
        shared_data->flag[i]=0;
        pid=fork();
        if (pid == -1)
        {
            printf("Error at fork!\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (pid == 0) { /* reader */
            while(!shared_data->flag[i]);
            FILE *file;
            file = fopen(shared_data->path[i], "r");
            if (file == NULL)
            {
                printf("Could not open/find the specified file.\n");
                return -1;
            }
            int size = 0;
            char readChar=NULL;
            char *msg = NULL;
            while((readChar = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
                msg = (char *) realloc(msg, size+1);
                *(msg + size) = readChar;
                size++;
            }
            *(msg + size) = '\0';

            int count = 0;
            while(msg = strstr(msg, shared_data->word[i]))
            {
                count++;
                msg++;
            }
            shared_data->number_ocurrency[i]=count;
            exit(0);
        }
        if(pid>0){
            shared_data->word[i]="SCOMP";
            char path[16]="files/file1.txt";
            shared_data->path[i]=malloc(sizeof(path)+1);
            sprintf(shared_data->path[i],"files/file%d.txt",i);
            //shared_data->path[i]= "files/file.txt";
            shared_data->number_ocurrency[i]=0;
            shared_data->flag[i]=1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<10;i++){
        wait(NULL);
    }


    for(i=0; i<10;i++){
        printf("The word %s in the son %d appeared: %d times\n",shared_data->word[i],i,shared_data->number_ocurrency[i]);
    }
    if (munmap(shared_data, data_size) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error at unmap!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(shm_unlink("/ex06_searchWord")==-1){
        perror("Error at unlink!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does it make sense to share pointers to non-shared memory among different processes?  Such pointers are meaningful / usable only in the process in which the pointed-to memory was allocated.

Comment: In any case, what is the actual question?

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}',  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line. 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the returned value from the function: `mmap()` has type `void*`.  A void pointer can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting that returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest removing the cast.

Comment: Sorry, I am an expert at `mmap` but I gave up reading on your question because of bad indentation and because it has way too much code for being a **minimal** example.

Comment: this line: `char readChar=NULL;`  has a problem.  `NULL` is a pointer, which is a multi byte entity, but a `char` is only a single byte.  Perhaps you meant to say: `char readChar='\0';`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )  As an example output from the compiler, the parameters to the function: `main()`  are not used, so the function signature should be: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  (I.E. 10)  Suggest using a `#define` statement to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding the code block beginning with: `while(msg = strstr(msg, shared_data->word[i]))`   The `i` is not being updated, so this loop, if it finds an instance of the `needle` in the `haystack` will loop forever

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Otherwise if not successful, any accessing of the returned value will result in undefined behaviour leading to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you share bytes between processes, you need to make sure those bytes contain something that is meaningful and understandable to all the processes that are going to use it. Putting pointers to memory that isn't shared in shared memory makes no sense. And unless all the processes can be guaranteed to map the shared memory at the same address, even putting absolute pointers to shared memory in shared memory makes no sense.

You can divide the shared memory into "slots" if you want and get the effect of having pointers in shared memory by placing the slot number in shared memory. The slot number will have to be translated to and from an absolute address in each process, taking into account the base address of the mapping.